PowerBI Dax - LASTNONBLANK
I am trying to write DAX that will return the name of a marketing campaign, where the date the person responded to the campaign is less than or equal to the date the opportunity was created.  The data is on separate tables.
For my model I have three tables.  A 'Campaign Member' table that holds the marketing response data, a person table (w/ person ID), and a opportunity table.
Here is what I have tried, however it is not pulling as expected.  Looking for some help.
Opportunity Create Campaign =
CALCULATE(
    LASTNONBLANK('Campaign Member'[Campaign Name],TRUE()),
    FILTER(
        'Campaign Member',
        Campaign Member'[Person ID]==Opportunities[Person ID] 
            && 'Campaign Member'[Responded]==TRUE() 
            && Opportunities[Opportunity Created Date] <= 'Campaign Member'[Campaign Member Association Date]
    )
)

I would expect the following
Some Big Deal 1 RETURN Some Marketing Campaign 4
Some Big Deal 2 RETURN Some Marketing Campaign 3
Some Big Deal 3 RETURN Some Marketing Campaign 3

Here is some screen shots of what the dax is returning incorrectly
Screen Shot of Expected Result

It would be easier if you include some sample data using a Mark down table. That way we don't have to invent your situation or hope that didn't state something incorrectly.

You were close with your DAX formula - you had the sign the wrong way round for the dates.
// you had
Opportunities[Opportunity Created Date] <= 'Campaign Member'[Campaign Member Association Date]
// change to
Opportunities[Opportunity Created Date] >= 'Campaign Member'[Campaign Member Association Date]

But be careful with LASTNONBLANK it is essentially the same as MAX, ie it will give you the max campaign name and not the one with the latest date.
Instead you can adopt an approach like @Ryan has suggested, where you get the max date and then filter on that a second time. Alternatively, you can leverage TOPN and do it in one go (the sort option is important here). Here is an example:
Opportunity Create Campaign = 
  var fTop1 = 
    TOPN(1,
      FILTER(
        'Campaign Member',
        'Campaign Member'[Person ID] = Opportunities[Person ID] &&
        'Campaign Member'[Responded] = TRUE() &&
        'Campaign Member'[Campaign Member Association Date] <= Opportunities[Opportunity Created Date]
      ),
      'Campaign Member'[Campaign Member Association Date], DESC
    )
  RETURN  CALCULATE( MAX('Campaign Member'[Campaign Name]), fTop1 )

For completeness, sharing the below tables for those who want to try it out (create the calculated column in the Opportunities table).
Opportunities table:



Person ID
Opportunity Created Date




A
26/02/2024


B
24/02/2024


C
27/02/2024



Campaign Member table:



Campaign Name
Campaign Member Association Date
Responded
Person ID




Some Marketing Campaign 1
2024-01-06
TRUE
C


Some Marketing Campaign 2
2024-01-23

C


Some Marketing Campaign 3
2024-02-09
TRUE
C


Some Marketing Campaign 4
2024-02-26

C


Some Marketing Campaign 5
2024-03-14

C


Some Marketing Campaign 6
2024-03-31

C


Some Marketing Campaign 7
2024-04-17

C


Some Marketing Campaign 8
2024-05-04

C


Some Marketing Campaign 1
2024-01-04
TRUE
B


Some Marketing Campaign 2
2024-01-21

B


Some Marketing Campaign 3
2024-02-07
TRUE
B


Some Marketing Campaign 4
2024-02-24

B


Some Marketing Campaign 5
2024-03-12

B


Some Marketing Campaign 6
2024-03-29

B


Some Marketing Campaign 7
2024-04-15
TRUE
B


Some Marketing Campaign 8
2024-05-02

B


Some Marketing Campaign 1
2024-01-02
TRUE
A


Some Marketing Campaign 2
2024-01-19
TRUE
A


Some Marketing Campaign 3
2024-02-05

A


Some Marketing Campaign 04
2024-02-22
TRUE
A


Some Marketing Campaign 5
2024-03-10

A


Some Marketing Campaign 6
2024-03-27

A


Some Marketing Campaign 7
2024-04-13
TRUE
A


Some Marketing Campaign 8
2024-04-30

A




you can try this to create a column
column =
VAR _date =
    MAXX (
        FILTER (
            'Campaigin Member',
            'Campaigin Member'[Person ID] = Opportunities[Person ID]
                && 'Campaigin Member'[Campaign Member Association Date] <= Opportunities[Opportunity Created Date]
                && 'Campaigin Member'[Responded] = TRUE ()
        ),
        'Campaigin Member'[Campaign Member Association Date]
    )
RETURN
    MAXX (
        FILTER (
            'Campaigin Member',
            Opportunities[Person ID] = 'Campaigin Member'[Person ID]
                && 'Campaigin Member'[Campaign Member Association Date] = _date
        ),
        'Campaigin Member'[Campagin Name]
    )


