backtrack to the data ,based on the value of a column
enter image description hereIn a table, i have calculated min of a column based on filters on other columns. Based on the min column, how can i backtrack to the data? to store it in another column. Please suggest solution in Power-B[
[enter image description here][2]

]3I.
I expect to get 66 in the new col, as per image, because it is the value corresponding to the lowest value in next right cell

You haven't provided enough detail or the image for us assist. In the mean time, see if this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78556269/powerbi-dax-lastnonblank

Also, there is no image

you can try this to create a column
column =
VAR _min =
    CALCULATE ( MIN ( 'Table'[KBERT] ), ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[LZONE] ) )
RETURN
    MAXX (
        FILTER (
            'Table',
            'Table'[LZONE] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[LZONE] )
                && 'Table'[KBERT] = _min
        ),
        'Table'[DISTZ]
    )


